# Sql server using variable in pivot query

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, pivot

I have a returned string from a query that reads:

```
 +----------------------+     
 |   returnquerystring  |
 +----------------------+
 |   exam1,exam2,exam3  |
 +----------------------+
```

I am using this returned string as column names in a pivot query.

```
 select * from (select score,exam from table1) x
 pivot ( max(score) for exam in (exam1,exam2,exam3)
```

This query works giving me

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
|    exam1    |   exam2   |   exam3   |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
|      10     |     20    |     30    |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

However I have not been able to get the pivot "in" statement to use anything but the hard coded values of exam1,exam2,exam3.  For example I have used SSMS and created a query that successfully puts exam1,exam2,exam3 into @var1.  However @var1 will throws and error when used in place of exam1,exam2,exam3.

```
 declare @var1 varchar(100)
 select @var1 = value from table 
 select * from (select score,exam from table1) x
 pivot ( max(score) for exam in (@var1)

 Incorrect syntax near '@var1'.
```

To verify that I was doing it correctly I did this and it worked.

```
 declare @var1 int
 select top 1 @var1 = id from name 
 select * from name where id = @var1
```

This provided the data row for id 1 on the name table with no error.

I have noticed in my experiments that (exam1,exam2,exam3) cannot be ('exam1,exam2,exam3') with the quotes.

I am using ColdFusion CFSCRIPT and it does appear that the single quotes are getting into the query so I tried various tests with ColdFusion functions to remove them with no success.

So I tried using the SQL Server function 'replace' around the @var1 and that throws an error about syntax at replace.

This is when I tried using an example like above in SSMS and still got errors.  So by removing ColdFusion from the equation it still does not work.  My thought was to send the whole declare through pivot as a query to avoid ColdFusion issues but it does not work in SSMS.

I am using SQL SERVER 8 and SSMS 11.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

```
 examColumns = exam1,exam2,exam3

public any function qryExamScores(string examColumns) {
    thisQry = new Query();
    thisQry.setName("returnqry");
    thisQry.setDatasource(application.datasource);
 thisQry.addParam(name="columnNames",value=arguments.examColumns,cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar");
    result = thisQry.execute(sql="
        select * from
        (select id,score,exam
        from table
        where value1 = 'XXXXX'
         and value2 = '11111') x
         pivot
         (
            max(score) for exam in (:columnNames)
         ) p

    ");
    returnqry = result.getResult();
    return returnqry;
}
```

Comment: FYI - if you need single quotes to be passed "as is" from ColdFusion you will need to use the function `preservesinglequotes( )` - otherwise CF helpully escapes single quotes assuming they are part of a character variable for insert or update.

Comment: I believe dynamic SQL will be required; however does table contain only one row?  in your verification you did a top 1, but in your select you didn't.  Made me think multiple rows may be comming back and the "in" can't handle that.

Comment: Mark it appears that ColdFusion is putting the single quotes in and I go not want them.  It is CFSCRIPT so I am passing exam1,exam2,exam3 as a param varchar as :parametervalue.  I get an error that appears that there are quotes but when I output the string coming into the function there are none.  If you have a way to use the ColdFusion I am all ears.

Comment: xQbert the process in ColdFusion what using one query to get exam1,exam2,exam3 and then pass that to another function to use it in the pivot query.  See my note to Mark.

Comment: We'd need to see your CF code. can you post it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `Dynamic SQL` to use the value of variable(@var1) inside `Pivot`

```
declare @var1 varchar(100)='',@sql nvarchar(max)
 select top 1 @var1 = value from table 

 set @sql = 'select * from (select score,exam from table1) x
 pivot ( max(score) for exam in (['+@var1+'])) piv'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

If you want to have more then one value in pivot columns use this.

```
SELECT @var1 += '[' + Isnull(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), value), '') + '],'
FROM   table

SELECT @var1 = LEFT(@var1, Len(@var) - 1)

SET @sql = 'select * from (select score,exam from table1) x
            pivot ( max(score) for exam in (' + @var1 + ')) piv'

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 2):

> passing exam1,exam2,exam3 as a param varchar as :parametervalue

Queryparam (or bind variables) can only be used on literals. Since "exam1,exam2,exam3" are being used as *column names* in this specific query, you cannot apply queryparam to them. When you do that, you are telling the database those values are simple strings. That causes an error because `pivot` expects object names, not strings.

Remove the queryparam and the query will work as expected. However, obviously that may expose your database to sql injection (depending on the source of `columnNames`). The same applies to using any dynamic SQL (`exec`, `sp_executesql`, ...). So be sure to fully validate the input before implementing this approach.

```
...
// build pivot statement with dynamic column names
columnNames = "exam1,exam2,exam3";
sqlString = "SELECT * 
             FROM  (
                     SELECT score,exam 
                     FROM   table1
                  ) x 
             PIVOT
             ( 
                MAX(score) FOR exam IN ("& columnNames &") 
             ) 
             AS pvt ";
result = qry.execute( sql=sqlString ).getResult(); 
writeDump( result );
```

**Edit:**

Also, you should probably enclose the column names in brackets to avoid syntax errors if the values contain spaces, or other invalid characters for column names.

```
 "[exam1],[exam2],[exam3]";
```

Comment: Leigh, thanks for the information.  I suspected the queryparam was the issue and wanted to figure away around it without removing it. I have successfully used the dynamic sql method and passed the whole as a query.  I will review to see which causes less of a security risk.  So now the dilemma of choosing only one correct answer for this post. There is the obvious solution which is to create a stored procedure in the database but when you are a contractor without the keys to the database you have to find a work around.

Comment: (Edit) Well, a stored proc would still be a risk because it too would require dynamic sql. Unfortunately, I do not think you can "parameterize" a `pivot` - with any method. So it may be six of one, half dozen of the other. Frankly, dynamic sql is always risky. So do not blindly allow the execution of just any sql string, and be sure to validate - *a lot* :) BTW, the other answer is perfectly valid. So feel free to pick whichever answer suited best here. I just wanted to add an explanation from the CF perspective to the archives.